# Как посчитать слова в Java без регулярных выражений?

Tags: java, строки

Подскажите пожалуйста, как посчитать слова в строке в Java?

Как я понимаю, программа должна считывать символы в цикле for, потом доходить до пробела и считать его как окончание слова. Но как тогда посчитать последнее слово?

Слова надо считывать с помощью метода `.length`, так? Но как тогда "объяснить в коде", что пробел это уже другое слово и у него своя длина?

И по условию мне нужно не просто считать слова, но ещё и пронумеровать их и вывести в строку, и как это сделать в `System.out.print();` я пока что тоже не могу понять.

Могу представить, как отдельно вывести строку и количество слов, но как их "перемешать" я совершенно не понимаю.

Comment: Что такое "слово" в вашем понимании: последовательность только букв; букв и цифр, букв, цифр и некоторых символов (дефис/апостроф); любых непробельных и непунктуационных символов? Что значит "без регулярных выражений" -- вам "запрещено" пользоваться методом `String::split`?  Можете ли вы пользоваться стандартными классами типа `Scanner` или устаревший `StringTokenizer`?

Comment: Слова в данном случае это скорее-всего будет набор букв и символов. 
StringTokenizer мы не проходили (только StringBuilder), как и метод split. Как вариант я планирую использовать метод indexOf() в цикле.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Метод `String::indexOf` ищет только некоторый заранее определённый символ, а не символы определённого класса.
Например, ко множеству пробельных символов относится не только пробел `' '`, но и [масса других](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/util/regex/Pattern.html):

- горизонтальные пробельные символы: **`[ \t\xA0\u1680\u180e\u2000-\u200a\u202f\u205f\u3000]`**
- вертикальные пробельные символы: **`[\n\x0B\f\r\x85\u2028\u2029]`**

Поэтому использовать `String::indexOf` имеет смысл только для *некоторых* входных строк, для которых заранее известно, что *все* слова разделены только пробелами.

В целом же основной алгоритм поиска слов (или их количества) без привлечения "тяжёлых" способов типа регулярных выражений / Stream API может выглядеть так:

- инициализировать счётчик слов или список найденных слов, создать буфер для "накопления" слова
- сделать внешний цикл `for` с переменными для текущего индекса символа в строке и количества символов входной строки `str`, соответственно, обращаясь к символам строки при помощи [`String::charAt(int index)`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/String.html#charAt(int)) (или более "продвинутые" юникодовские кодовые точки [`String::codePointAt(int index)`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/String.html#codePointAt(int)))
- в первом вложенном цикле "пропустить" все символы, НЕ относящиеся к словам, например, при помощи метода [`Character.isAlphabetic`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/Character.html#isAlphabetic(int)) или [`Character.isLetterOrDigit`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/Character.html#isLetterOrDigit(char)) и логического отрицания `!` или же используя [`Character.isWhitespace`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/Character.html#isWhitespace(char))
- очистить буфер
- в следующем вложенном цикле добавить в буфер все символы, относящиеся к словам при помощи соответствующего метода [`Character.isAlphabetic`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/Character.html#isAlphabetic(int)) или [`Character.isLetterOrDigit`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/Character.html#isLetterOrDigit(char)) и т.п.
- после окончания второго вложенного цикла, если буфер непустой, инкрементировать счётчик слов, вывести текущее слово при необходимости или добавить найденное слово в список-результат
- по окончании внешнего цикла вывести/вернуть итоговый результат

В обоих вложенных циклах следует проверять условия выхода за границы строки.

---

Реализация вышеописанного алгоритма достаточно тривиальна и соответствующий код НЕ приводится намеренно.

---

Пример поиска слов в строке при помощи класса `Scanner`:

```java
public static List<String> getWordsSc(String str) {
    Scanner sc = new Scanner(str);
    List<String> result = new ArrayList<>();
    while (sc.hasNext()) {
        result.add(sc.next());
    }
    
    return result;
}
```

Однако по умолчанию сканер будет разделять строку только по пробельным символам, то есть при наличии знаков пунктуации они будут "входить" в слова.

Answer (score 0):

Не все понятно из вопроса, исхожу из того, что у Вас есть строка, вы ее видите и нужно посчитать слова (вообще вариантов это сделать много, можно и стримы использовать, но так как Вы начинающий разработчик, предлагаю способ, который проще для понимания):

```
//Ваша строка
String s = "Вместе весело шагать по просторам\n" +
            "По просторам, по просторам\n" +
            "И, конечно, напевать лучше хором\n" +
            "Лучше хором, лучше хором";
//убираем из строки знак переноса строки и запятые
String onlyWord = s.replace(",","").replace("\n"," ");
//делим строку на слова по пробелу и записываем их в массив
String [] arrWord = onlyWord.split(" ");
//размер массива равен количеству слов, выводим соответствующее сообщение
System.out.println("В строке " + arrWord.length + " слов(а)");
//в цикле выводим все слова под их порядковыми номерами
for (int i = 0; i < arrWord.length; i++) {
System.out.print("Слово №" + (i+1) + ": " + arrWord[i]+", ");
}
```

У меня получился такой результат

```
В строке 18 слов(а)
Слово №1: Вместе, Слово №2: весело, Слово №3: шагать, Слово №4: по, Слово №5: просторам, Слово №6: По, Слово №7: просторам, Слово №8: по, Слово №9: просторам, Слово №10: И, Слово №11: конечно, Слово №12: напевать, Слово №13: лучше, Слово №14: хором, Слово №15: Лучше, Слово №16: хором, Слово №17: лучше, Слово №18: хором,
```

По поводу того, что вы не проходили метод split: в классе String не менее 50 методов, split один из них. Не думаю, что вы проходили бы все 50 методов. Вероятнее всего Вам дали домашнее задание с тем уклоном, чтобы Вы самостоятельно ознакомились с методами класса, которые не разбирали на занятии.

Comment: Для подсчета слов ничего делить на части не надо. Достаточно последовательно перебирать все символы в строке и понимать, что программа находится всего лишь в 2-х состояниях 1) внутри слова и 2) вне слова (это исходное состояние). Переход их одного в другое осуществляется анализом очередного символа (контекстно-зависимо, т.е. роль символа в разных состояниях разная, для анализа перехода (или не перехода) нужны всего-то две битовых строки (код символа используется как индекс в строке) ). При переходе из (2) в (1) счетчик слов увеличивается.

Answer (score 0):

Пример со `split` не совсем корректен, так как не учитывает все разделители и несколько разделителей подряд, зачем-то меняет переносы строк на пробелы.

`split` может принимать в себя регулярное выражение и мы можем написать просто

```java
s.split("\\s+").length
```