# Как посчитать количество слов в строке без использования массивов

Tags: java, строки, методы

Подскажите, пожалуйста, какими методами в java можно посчитать количество слов( именно слов!)в строке не используя массивы!

Comment: Посчитать количество пробелов в строке, к примеру :)

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Посчитать количество слов в тексте](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1448136/); [Количество "слов" в строке](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/107220/); [Как посчитать слова в Java без регулярных выражений?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1531972/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Для подсчёта слов сначала следует определить, что такое слово.

Например, если словом является последовательность одного и более буквенных символов, т.е. слова удовлетворяют регулярному выражению `"\\p{L}+"`, можно посчитать при помощи Stream API:

```java
public static int wordCount(String txt) {
    if (null == txt || txt.isEmpty()) {
        return 0;
    }
    return (int) Pattern.compile("\\p{L}+").matcher(txt).results().count();
}
```

Аналогично в "олдскульном стиле" при помощи цикла:

```java
public static int wordCountLoop(String txt) {
    if (null == txt || txt.isEmpty()) {
        return 0;
    }
    Matcher m = Pattern.compile("\\p{L}+").matcher(txt);
    int count = 0;
    while (m.find()) count++;
    return count;
}
```

Такой способ проще модифицировать, если поменяется шаблон-определение слова, например, в него просто добавить какие-нибудь дополнительные символы типа апострофа, дефиса и т.п.

Также он более надёжен, чем подсчёт слов по количеству пробелов, вернее пробельных и/или пунктуационных символов, которых существует превеликое множество, и которые могут быть или отсутствовать в начале/конце строки.

---

Аналогично можно посчитать слова по количеству промежутков между ними, то есть, по *последовательностям* пробельных и/или пунктуационных символов.

Обычно для этого используется старый добрый метод `String::split` с разбивкой строки по не-буквенным символам (класс `"P{L}+"`):

```java
public static int wordCountBySplit(String txt) {
    if (null == txt) {
        return 0;
    }
    return txt.split("\\P{L}+").length;
}
```

Недостаток такой реализации в том, что неверно обрабатываются краевые случаи типа пустой строки, строки, содержащей только разделители, или с разделителями в начале и конце.   Поэтому следует очистить начало / конец входной строки, чтобы не посчитать пустую строку в качестве слова и дополнительно обработать случай получившейся пустой строки:

```java
public static int wordCountBySplit(String txt) {
    if (null == txt) {
        return 0;
    }
    txt = txt.replaceAll("^\\P{L}+|\\P{L}+$", ""); // очистка начала/конца строки вместо trim()
    return txt.isEmpty() ? 0 : txt.split("\\P{L}+").length;
}
```

Однако `String::split` создаёт массив строк, то есть условно запрещён, поэтому также придётся воспользоваться `Matcher`, но с коррекцией на 1:

```java
public static int wordCount(String txt) {
    if (null == txt) {
        return 0;
    }
    txt = txt.replaceAll("^\\P{L}+|\\P{L}+$", ""); // очистка начала/конца строки вместо trim()
    return txt.isEmpty() ? 0 : (int) Pattern.compile("\\P{L}+").matcher(txt).results().count() + 1;
}
```

---

Если регулярные выражения также запрещены, следует воспользоваться кодом с циклом, представленном в [ответе](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1448341/386633) на вопрос-дубликат [Посчитать количество слов в тексте](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1448136/), слегка улучшив его:

```java
public static int wordCountPlain(String txt) {
    int count = 0;

    if (null != txt) {
        boolean wordBegin = true;
        for (char c : txt.toCharArray()) {
            if (Character.isLetter(c)) { // любая буква
                if (wordBegin) {
                    wordBegin = false;
                    count++;
                }
            } else {
                wordBegin = true;
            }
        }
    }
    return count;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Допустим, это можно сделать так:

```
String str = " qwer asdf zxcv  ";
int count = str.trim().length() - str.trim().replaceAll(" ", "").length() + 1;
println("Слов в строке: " + count);
```

Берем строку, убираем пробелы в начале и в конце строки.

Берем длину полученной строки и вычитаем длину строки без пробелов - разница, это количество пробелов, которое было в строке.

Количество пробелов + 1 = количество слов в строке

Comment: Между словами вполне может быть более одного пробела или даже другие пробельные символы.

Comment: Да, это больше всего и интересует. Нужно устранить лишние пробельные символы/пробелы между словами? Или есть другой метод?